# How to use a pi zero as NFS client/USB stick?

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, nfs

I have a Google **Chromecast** with an app that I would like to connect to my NFS share on my **NAS**. The app does not have a built-in NFS (or smb) client, so there is no way I can make the connection directly.

I got an idea, but I am not sure whether it is possible: maybe I can connect my pi zero w to the Chromecast and present it as a USB drive and then, on the pi, mount the NFS share on the NAS and let that mount point be the “USB drive”. That way, the Chromecast will see a USB drive which in reality is a directory on my NAS. However, I am not sure how to set it up. Has anyone tried something like this?